# Backup Signal Desktop chats

Tags: backup, database, signal-app

I'd like to have a portable version of the Signal Messenger (packed like all the apps from [portableapps.com](https://portableapps.com/) or any other similar site) in order to be able to just copy a folder to an external hard drive so that in the future, if my main install gets corrupted I can just roll back to an old one, but there isn't.

So far the only way to use Signal on a Windows machine is to install their "Desktop version" which essentially is just a chromium browser package made with electron that runs their programme as a web application. Seeing this, I thought that it should be possilbe to use it in another way that allows backups. On the Unix Stack Exchange I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505008/signal-desktop-how-to-export-messages) post on how to back up Signal chat history, but it is written for bash and has only limited useability as it only can backup already loaded chats, not force Signal to load everything. In addition, so far I didn't find out how to restore the chats from such a backup.

In the end I don't mind how it is stored or how secure it is as I will just have the backup on a NAS in my basement to be prepared when I brick my system again and as the desktop app doesn't allow to read old messages that were sent before the last installation, it would be really helpful to just load a backup.

For the worst case scenario I would also take a backup directly from the iPhone I use as primary device, but as far as I know this isn't possible as well.